# dlopen : symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN2v810ScriptData10PreCompileEPKci' on Mac m1 (Monterey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, homebrew, therubyracer

using Mac M1 - macOS Monterey 12.1

ruby version

```
ruby 2.6.9p207 (2021-11-24 revision 67954) [arm64-darwin21]
```

rails versions

```
Rails 5.1.5
```

After installing gem

```
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```

whenever I start the puma server/ rails server, getting this error.

> dlopen(/Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN2v810ScriptData10PreCompileEPKci' - /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle (LoadError)

Comment: did you solve this problem bro? i have the same issue

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any solutions?

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve that?